# onRequestPermissionsResult leads to Failure delivering result

Tags: android

I am trying to request location permissions in a Fragment that I add to my activity. I handle the `@override onRequestPermissionsResult` in my activity and then I try to close my fragment by calling:

I create a fragment to show and ask for permissions in the onCreate of my activity:

```
    public class HomeActivity extends BaseTabBarActivity {
private static final int ACCESS_LOCATION = 1;
private ActivityHomeBinding binding;

PermissionFragment permissionFragment;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    permissionFragment = new PermissionFragment();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home);
    Account account = new Account();

    binding.setAccount(account);

    if (!checkLocationPermission()) {
        permissionFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Permission Dialog");
    }
}
```

I then request permissions in my fragment like this:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_permission, container, false);
    binding.setPermissionType(PermissionType.LOCATION);
    binding.btnProceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (binding.getPermissionType().equals(PermissionType.LOCATION)) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_LOCATION);
                    return;
                }
                closePermissionDialog();
            } else {
                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

And then when I return from the permissions request with this:

```
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == ACCESS_LOCATION) {
        if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionFragment.dismiss();
        } else {
            permissionFragment.binding.setPermissionType(PermissionFragment.PermissionType.LOCATION_DENIED);
        }
    }
}
```

The code which causes the error is in the fragment and is this method:

```
    public void closePermissionDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    ft.detach(this);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

When this transaction is attempted to commit, it happens after the Activity's onSaveInstanceState is saved, which according to the Android documentation is what leads to my error:

"A transaction can only be committed with this method prior to its containing activity saving its state. If the commit is attempted after that point, an exception will be thrown. This is because the state after the commit can be lost if the activity needs to be restored from its state. See commitAllowingStateLoss() for situations where it may be okay to lose the commit." - Android Google Docs on this page: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()

What is the best strategy to eradicate to prevent this flow of activity cycles? I clearly am not doing anything that is the right way to handle the flow between the activity and fragment.

I get the following error:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {.android/.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2044)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2067)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:680)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:634)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:205)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:171)
                                                                           at com.activities.HomeActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(HomeActivity.java:92)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6582)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6460)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

Comment: Did you try to override onSaveInstanceState() without calling the super() ?

Comment: Try my library, probably it won't cause the problem. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: put your onRequestPermissionsResult code as well

Comment: Levon but isn't that a hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I moved the check permissions from using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` which always resulted in the callback of onSaveInstanceState on the activity being called before the transaction to dismiss the fragment was called, to using the Fragment's requestPermission which guarantees that i am out of the fragments transaction before onSaveInstance state is called on my Activity:

```
        binding.btnProceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (binding.getPermissionType().equals(PermissionType.LOCATION)) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_LOCATION);
                    return;
                }
                closePermissionDialog();
            } else {
                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```